# Database to DropDownList and AutoPostBack to Label

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, drop-down-menu, label

I have a code like this

```
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlServerCstr"].ConnectionString;

                SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
                myConnection.Open();
string musisim = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select B.HESAP_NO FROM  YAZ..MARDATA.S_TEKLIF B WHERE B.MUS_K_ISIM = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value", myConnection);

                Label1.Text = cmd.ExecuteReader().ToString();

                myConnection.Close();
```

i have a customer name as "MUS_K_ISIM" and his number as "HESAP_NO"

All i want is, (autopostback is true) automaticly getting label "HESAP_NO" with who has this number "MUS_K_ISIM" in Dropdownlist.

How can i do that?

**Error:** Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Comment: Please use try catch block to get exception description

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your database doesn't know anything about your ASP page or controls on it ;-) so you'll need to re-work your SQL statement - As a first revision you could change it thus:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select B.HESAP_NO FROM  YAZ..MARDATA.S_TEKLIF B WHERE B.MUS_K_ISIM = '" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value + "'", myConnection);
```

so that the name selected in your dropdownlist will be added to the SQL query.

Looking ahead, its best to do this kind of thing with either a [Parameterized Query](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson06.aspx) or a [Stored procedure](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson07.aspx).

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Hi just use a parametrized query like this

Also there is likely a typo in table name YAZ..MARDATA.S_TEKLIF in query it might be 'YAZ.MARDATA.S_TEKLIF'

**Updated code**

```
string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlServerCstr"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
        {
            string query = "select B.HESAP_NO FROM  YAZ.MARDATA.S_TEKLIF B WHERE B.MUS_K_ISIM = @selectedItem";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@selectedItem", DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString());
                myConnection.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (dr.HasRows)
                    {
                        Label1.Text = dr["B.HESAP_NO"].ToString();
                    }
                    dr.Close();
                }
            }
            myConnection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Hi, YAZ..MARDATA.S_TEKLIF is true because it is a link server :) By the way, DataReader is in System.Data.SqlClient? Is this wrong?

Comment: Sorry about that, checked the corrected code now. It is actually SqlDataReader & yes you will find this inside System.Data.SqlClient namespace.Use this code inside selectedIndex change event of your dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select B.HESAP_NO FROM  YAZ..MARDATA.S_TEKLIF B WHERE B.MUS_K_ISIM = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value", myConnection);
```

Are you hardcoding the text ?, You need to pass the selected value i presume, the one in

```
musisim
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to connect to the DB with code. You can do all this with one line of code.

Add a SqlDataSource and configure it with the SQL command you need.

Connect the DropDown to the SqlDataSource, configure what column should be connected to the Text Field and what column should be connected to the Value field.

In your function     DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged

Just do this:

```
 Label1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue();
```

Comment: No StefanE. DropDownList1.SelectedValue() is customer name. what i want, label.text = dropdownlist.selectedvalue().number with where ii can get this number from database. for example like this. Can i explain??

Comment: StefanE is right, why the down vote ? This can all be done with a simple Sql/Object datasource. It all depends on the user's requirements.

Comment: For someone new to ADO and .Net the advice to 'Add a SQLDatasource ...' isn't terribly helpful. You can see he's pretty much there with his query, why not run with his plan first so he can get his head around the basic concepts? Its important to learn _why_ things are as they were rather than blindly learning _how to_ do it.

Comment: There is a lot of advantages in general to use an SQL Datasource and specifically if you are new to ADO in my opinion. I tried direct him in the right direction without have to add 4000 lines of explanation of how to use a SQL Datasource.